# How do PHP arrays actually work?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm learning PHP and I've got a question that's bothering me.  PHP arrays seem to be hashmaps internally.  If you give an array a key and value, it almost certainly has to put the key through some sort of hashing function before placing it in an actual array, right?  Why then, if I give an array a series of keys and values and then dump these to screen, does PHP maintain the order in which I entered the values?

for instance:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = 'one';
$arr[3] = 'three';
$arr[2] = 'two';

foreach($arr as $key => $val)
    echo "$key => $val<br>"
```

would render "`1 => one, 2 => two, 3 => three`" in a typical hashmap, but instead I get "`1 => one, 3 => three, 2 => two`."  Which to me means that there have to be both and order and a key being maintained in whatever datatype this actually is.

Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Comment: First line in the docs: "_An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.  A map is a type that associates values to keys_"  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php So yes, they are ordered.

Comment: Short answer is it's something like javas linkedHashMap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about the array being stored as a hash table or ordered map.  Basically, everything in PHP is a hash table.

See here: [Understanding PHP's internal array implementation](http://nikic.github.io/2012/03/28/Understanding-PHPs-internal-array-implementation.html)

Comment: Right, but a hash table shouldn't keep track of the fact that I added 3 before 2.

Comment: Sure.  If you look at the link the hash table contains arBucket for buckets that contain pListNext and pListLast for arrays.